# arguments not working in jquery terminal plugin

Tags: jquery, electron, jquery-terminal

I have been recently working on an electron application which uses jquery terminal plugin. I am using cmd function of the plugin and want to pass an argument while giving the command and then print both the args. my whole renderer.js file is given below:

```
var pre = $('pre');
var body = $('body');
function scroll_to_bottom() {
  var sHeight = body.prop('scrollHeight');
  body.scrollTop(sHeight);
}
var cmd = $('#some_id').cmd({
  prompt: ' ',
  width: '100%',
  commands: function(command, argd) {
    var html = pre.html();
    if (html) { html += '\n'; }
    var message = "you've typed " + 
        "<span style=\"color:white\">" + command + " " + argd
        "</span>";
    pre.html(html + '> ' + command + '\n' + message);
    scroll_to_bottom();
    
  }
});
```

Comment: I would answer sooner if you would add tag `[jquery-terminal]` or ask on GitHub or gitter.

Answer (score 0):

cmd plugin only accept single argument which is whole command that you type. In order to have command and arguments you need to parse the string you will get from the callback:

```js
var cmd = $('#some_id').cmd({
  prompt: ' ',
  width: '100%',
  commands: function(command) {
    var cmd = $.terminal.parse_command(command);
    // cmd.name == name of the command
    // cmd.args == array of arguments
    // cmd.rest == rest of the command as string
  }
});
```